# Bind ng-options in ng-model on loading (like a bidirectional binding)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

**The situation:**

I have the following select:

```
<select ng-model="model" ng-options="o as o.name for o in options track by o.code">
    <option value="">- Default -</option>
</select>
```

My `options` datas are like this:

```
$scope.options = [{id: 1, code: 'foo', name: 'Foo!'}, {id: 2, code: 'bar', name: 'Bar!'}];
```

**What I want to do:**

I want to have my select with a pre-selected value. My constraint is that I only know the `code` attribute of my object. With the help of the `track by` notation I can do that simply like this:

```
$scope.model = {code: 'bar'};
```

And it works, the selected value of the select is "Bar!"

**The problem:**

When I send this data to my backend, I need to send the `id` attribute of my object. The data sent is `{code: 'bar'}` but not `{id: 2, code: 'bar', name: 'Bar!'}` as I want.

For me it is the normal behavior... because I stored in my model `{code: 'bar'}` and I did not change the value selected.

**The conclusion:**

Is there a way to tell to AngularJS to copy the value from the `options` list to `model` when there is a default value in `model` (when there is a match using the `track by` notation) ?

> **Info:** I know that I can do something like this `$scope.model = $scope.options[2]` (with some logic to determine the index...) but I would like something more magical... If it is possible... :D

Comment: go through this: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select

Comment: Track by the `id`, if possible, could solve your issue.

Comment: I don't know the `id`, so I can't do that: `$scope.model = {id: 2};`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **OP Info**: I know that I can do something like this $scope.model = $scope.options[2] (with some logic to determine the index...) but I would like something more magical... If it is possible... :D

---

I have 3 magic's for your 3 objects

### Magic 1 :

```
$scope.model = $scope.options.filter(function(item) {
  return item.code=== 'bar';
})[0];
```

### Magic 2:

```
app.filter('getById', function() {
  return function(input, id) {
    var i=0, len=input.length;
    for (; i<len; i++) {
      if (+input[i].id == +id) {
        return input[i];
      }
    }
    return null;
  }
});

$scope.model  = $filter('getById')($scope.options, 2);
```

### Magic 3

```
angular.forEach($scope.options, function(option) {
        $scope.model = option.name == "name";
        if($scope.model !=null){break}
    });
```

Comment: Why so lengthy loops and filter. Look at my answer. As simple as it is.

Comment: Being a developer we should be able to avoid loops as much as possible. The code that works without loops are always optimal and better than one that has loops. Think when there will be 1000 options for the dropdown.

Comment: I think that the best option is the first one. There is less magic as I expected ;) but I think that there is no more alternative... Thank you !

Comment: By the way in your `Magic 3` I think that the break is useless. You can not use break in `angular.forEach()` https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/263#issuecomment-8153737

Comment: I mean you can go out from the loop by using `return false; | break;`.

Comment: I don't think so. The `break` will do nothing. The `return  false;` will stop the callback function at iteration `n` but after that the callback function will be call to the iteration `n+1` and so on.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a `ng-change` on the `<select>` and then create a function that will look for the selected option and its corresponding JSON model. Use this

HTML

```
<div ng-app='app' ng-controller='mainCtrl'>
    <select ng-model="model" ng-options="o as o.name for o in options track by o.code" 
    ng-change='getValue(this)'>
    <option value="">- Default -</option>
</select>
</div>
```

CONTROLLER

```
angular.module('app',['QuickList']).controller('mainCtrl', function($scope){
   $scope.options = [{id: 1, code: 'foo', name: 'Foo!'}, {id: 2, code: 'bar', name: 'Bar!'}];
   $scope.model = {code: 'bar'};
   $scope.getValue = function(item){
      console.log($scope.selectedOption = item.model);
   }
});
```

Whenever you will select the option in the `<select>` box you will see the actual JSON object for that option printed in the console.

Here is the working [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ves7gx6b/1/)

Comment: What  will happen if he does not select any options?

Comment: If he selects '- Default -' then it will be null as it do not have any JSON structure associated with it.

Comment: Actually my problem happens when I do not touch the select and submit the form, so this solution does not solve the problem. Thank you for the time you spent on it anyway :)

Comment: Well thanks, hope i will solve your next issue in near future.